# Connecting to outllok using oAuth2.0 throwing "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

Have created a simple code to connect to outlook using below sample code but the C# code throwing  "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." exception.

Code snippet.

```
  // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0
            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"])
                .WithClientSecret(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"])
                .WithTenantId(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"])
                .Build();

            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

            try
            {
               
                  var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
                                                  

                // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
                var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
                ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
                ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
                    new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "capmodauthtesting@test.com");

                //Include x-anchormailbox header
                ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "capmodauthtesting@test.com");

                // Make an EWS call
                var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(10));
                foreach(var folder in folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Folder: {folder.DisplayName}");
                }
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
            }
            catch (Exception  ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Error: {ex}");
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message   );
            }

            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

The code is from microsost

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth#code-samples

Comment: On what line does it crash, does the inner Exception specfiy any additional information?
In general, the issue is most likely with the token you've generated being wrong (due to wrong input).

Comment: Do you have appId, clientSecret, tenantId?

Comment: The code crashes when trying to acqure the Token for client. Can see the inner exception as "The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on send"

Comment: I can see TLS1,1.1 AND 1.2 but only 1.2 is enabled and other two are disabled.